# POO-Comparación de objetos en C++

Tags: c++, poo, algoritmos, genericos

**¿Hay alguna manera de comparar objetos en C++?**

Por ejemplo, se tiene una clase que es un árbol binario de búsqueda genérico, es decir un `ABB<T>` y se requiere comparar dos objetos de tipo genérico. Pensaba sobrecargar los operadores, pero creo que solo funcionaría para datos primitivos.

Bueno, en caso tenga objetos de otra clases, supongamos:

```
Clase Persona
    Atributos:
       int identificador
       string nombres
       string apellidos
       int anios
-----------------------
```

y tengo un arbol binario de busqueda de esta manera:

```
ABB<Persona> *arbol = new Arbol<Persona>()
```

deseo saber si los objetos de esta Clase Persona que son `*p1` y `*p2` (apuntadores) son iguales, mayor o menor que el otro.

En el caso de comparar atributo por atributo, considero que solo me serviría con esa clase y la idea es que el árbol sea genérico(que sirva para todos) ya que pueden haber otras clases que pueden tener más o menos atributos que la clase Persona e incluso con tipos de datos distintos.

Quiero saber que requiero hacer para estas situaciones.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y si no comparas atributo por atributo, como seria tu comparacion? al ser un lenguaje compilado, yo desconozco (y dudo que lo tenga) que exista reflection....

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por responder. Justamente eso también estaba pensando, pero tal vez el problema esté relacionado a containers del STL, pero no estoy seguro. Por eso, es mi pregunta ya que desconozco que haya una forma de hacer lo que mencioné en el post sobre mi situación.

Comment: Y como defines la igualdad si las clases otras clases pueden tener una cantidad diferente  de atributos? Como la defines si llevan tipos de datos distintos?